How to understand "Were somebody to do something, bla-bla-bla"?
I've seen two sentences like this:

Were Ireland to introduce student fees, either students from poor families would be debt-burdened or they would be prevented from getting a third-level education at all.


The protest march, were it to go ahead, would attract a large number of participants; such is the anger among students.

It seems like the meaning here is:
"Were somebody to do something, bla-bla-bla" = "If somebody did something, bla-bla-bla would happen"
Your opinion?

Yes, you have it Were something to happen uses the subjunctive mood (to discuss a hypothetical event) and the consequence is usually expressed using 'would'. Were I to put my hand in the fire, I would burn my fingers. Many people, but not all,  consider the subjunctive to be obsolete in English, or if not, excessively literary, formal, stiff, etc.

This question is similar to: What "were to " means in these sentences?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OP's query is regarding the structure of the Second Conditional sentences below:

1. Were Ireland to introduce student fees, either students from poor families would be debt-burdened or they would be prevented from getting a third-level education at all.
.
2. The protest march, were it to go ahead, would attract a large number of participants; such is the anger among students.


"If somebody did something" can describe either a hypothetical conditional (imaginary/unreal situation) or a past real conditional (describing something that actually happened).
In these examples, however, the structure:
"Were + subject + to + base verb" indicates hypothetical conditions.
This is a formal variation of the second conditional.

Why They Are Second Conditional:

Both sentences imagine hypothetical situations that are unlikely or unreal in the present or future:


In the first sentence, we imagine a hypothetical scenario where Ireland introduces student fees.
In the second, we imagine a hypothetical scenario where the protest march goes ahead.


Second conditional

The second conditional is used to imagine present or future situations that are impossible or unlikely in reality.
I wouldn't worry if I were you.
The structure is usually: if + past simple >> + would + infinitive.
When if is followed by the verb be, it is grammatically correct to say if I were, if he were, if she were and if it were.


Source: British Council
